# Improving resiliency of a workflow using Active MQ messaging system

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jms, activemq-classic

```
Method(){
Step1 {
1.  Gather few items
2.  Build a flat file-1
3.  SFTP the file-1
4.  Update a database
}
Step 2{
1.  Gather few items
2.  Build a flat file-2
3.  SFTP the file-2
4.  Update a database different database
}
Update another table saying the two steps are completed
}
```

The above method listens to an Active MQ queue and processes the workflow as mentioned above. Its fine if everything goes good and we transmit the two files successfully and update the required databases.

Issue/Improvement:

We have an existing utility which can republish the same Active MQ message.  If something goes wrong in the workflow, this tool will publish the same message back into the queue.  The method() listens to the queue and consume the message then rerun the whole workflow again. Essentially this is like a restart button, where we can play a move again from the beginning (but not anywhere in between).
This mechanism is very helpful only if we fail in the step1 before transmitting the file-1. However, if an exception happens in the step-2 (after the first file is already sent). Republishing (restarting the whole process) can potentially send the file-1 twice (once before exception occurred and once after we republish message).

Question:

I am looking for a solution where I can just resume from where I left before. For instance something goes wrong in Step 2.  I should be able to come back, resume from step two and avoid the step -1.

Work arounds:

I tried some flags for each check point and verify that at each step, this doesn’t look clean enough. I am wondering if we have any better solution for this? With Java, Spring, active MQ, etc. How can we serialize this?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? It's hard to follow and understand the essence of it.

Comment: @PetterNordlander i tried to rephrase the question, please let me know if it makes more sense.